# How can I compile data returned from an $http request?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having a recurring issue where I am unable to use directives that are included inside of template partials retrieved via $http. I assume that I need to use `$compile` or `$apply` to the template in order to get the directives to work. The following code attempts to use $apply on returned data from `$http` but it doesn't work:

```
$http({
    url: 'get/data',
    method: "POST"
})
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
     $scope.$apply(function () {
         $scope.data = data;
     });
})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) { $scope.status = status; });
```

The returned value (`data`) is simply a template that contains some HTML that has a few directives in it. If I write

```
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) { $scope.data = data }
```

then the template loads, but any directives in the template won't work. So I figured I need to use `$apply` or `$compile` to bind the directives to angular. There is clearly something fundamental that I'm missing in my understanding of angular and how directives can be bound to work in dynamically loaded templates. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You'd better create a directive for doing that since manipulate Dom is not angular's way.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that you need to use the $compile service to handle directives in dynamically loaded template. $compile processes some html and returns a linking function. When the linking function is called with a scope, it returns the fully compiled and linked template with functioning directives. This template must then be inserted into the live DOM. As zsong points out, this implies that all this should really be done in a directive, which is the domain of DOM manipulation in Angular. In one line:

```
container.html($compile(loadedHtml)(scope))
```

container is the element in the DOM that will contain the dynamic template. We set its html to the result of linking the compiled html to the scope.

Answer (score -1):

You could just load template via templateUrl (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).
The basic idea is that you write you directive in js, it's matching html in separate file which can be included in that directive via templateUrl.